# Why does this python re match?

Tags: python, regex

Can someone explain this weird behavior of python re? Obviously the string 'test' does not contain either 'Bid' or 'Ask'. Why is this matching?

```
import re
pat=r'[Bid|Ask]'
reg=re.compile(pat)
if reg.search('test'): print "matched!"
```

... 
matched!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`[...]`defines a character class, matching any character listed inside. What you wanted is `par = r'(Bid|Ask)'`.

However, you should **not use regex for this at all**, do the following instead:

```
if whatever in ('Bid', 'Ask'):
    # it's one of these two
else:
    # it isn't
```

If you need to perform a substring check (thanks @agf):

```
if any(word in whatever for word in ('Bid', 'Ask')):
    # one of the words is in the sting whatever
```

Comment: +1 for being faster and suggesting a better way without needing regex.

Comment: Or possibly `any(word in text for word in ('Bid', 'Ask'))` depending on if you want to accept substring matches.

Comment: Ahh. Thanks. Actually, I need to match any line that contains either Bid or Ask so I think I still need to use re.

Comment: @DavidJohnston See my first comment. @Platinum `don't ping me, ping him!`.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure Pretty sure you just pinged me and ThiefMaster... did you add then remove an `@David` or something?

Comment: @DavidJohnston See agf's comment. Really, it works. (Apologies to ThiefMaster, for some reason I thought I was in the question's comments)

Answer (score 5):

`[...]` is the [character class matcher](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), which means it will match any character in the set.

You probably wanted alternation, like this: `r'(Bid|Ask)'`.

Comment: You don't need the parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression is simply a character set containing the characters 'B', 'i', 'd', '|', 'A', 's', and 'k'. There is an 's' in 'test'.

What you probably meant was "(Bid|Ask)"

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `()` instead of `[]`. You've told it to match on any single character in the group `Bid|Ask` and the string contains `s`.

Comment: (The string contains *s*, not *d*.)

Comment: @kojiro, thanks - I was looking at the output string, not the input!

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is searching for the set of characters B,i,d,|,A,s,k. 's' matches inside 'test'.

You should omit the brackets.

Also if you don't want to match strings like "Askify" you'll need to refine your regex a little more.